# Semantic UI Add RTL CSS files

Tags: semantic-ui

Hi to Semantic UI Developers,

How can I have RTL CSS files of Semantic UI in Github ,

I need to have those files on CDN sites

How I can add those files in Github to update CDNs automatically?

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/semantic-ui
or
https://www.jsdelivr.com/projects/semantic-ui

Thank you very much

Comment: I doubt Semantic UI developers are watching this. Did you try this? https://github.com/jsdelivr/libgrabber#add-updatejson-schema or `//cdn.jsdelivr.net/{projectName}/latest/{file}`

Comment: @ManojKumar I hope which developers attention to this, otherwise I should make another github fork for that, But I prefer to have it on the original repository, RTL files are not hosted on origin Github repository